# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero - Python

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I understand why I'm getting this error but I'm struggling to think of a way around it....

My code which tries to calculate the percentage difference between values in a list:

```
values = [0.52, 0.42, 0.0, 0.65, 0.45]
conversion_values = []

for x in range(1, len(values), 1):
    val_1 = values[x-1]*100
    val_2 = values[x]*100
    diff = (val_2/val_1)*100
    conversion_values.append(int(round(diff)))
```

expected output:

```
conversion_values
[81, 0, '-', 69]
```

Comment: Is dividing zero by something not allowed either?

Comment: Why is the second element of the `conversion_values` equal to `-`? It should be `0`, since you can perform division, right?

Comment: yeah i guess that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to modify your existing code, you could do it this way:

```
values = [0.52, 0.42, 0.0, 0.65, 0.45]
conversion_values = []

for x in range(1, len(values), 1):
    val_1 = values[x-1]*100
    if val_1 == 0: #Check if val_1 is 0.
        conversion_values.append('-')
    else:
        val_2 = values[x]*100
        diff = (val_2/val_1)*100
        conversion_values.append(int(round(diff)))
print(conversion_values)
```

The output would be:

```
[81, 0, '-', 69]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the following will do what you want.

```
values = [0.52, 0.42, 0.0, 0.65, 0.45]
conversion_values = []

for x in range(1, len(values), 1):
    val_1 = values[x-1]*100
    val_2 = values[x]*100
    try:
        diff = (val_2/val_1)*100
        conversion_values.append(int(round(diff)))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        conversion_values.append('-')
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, went with Vasilis because I didn't want to use try and except even though that might be the right thing to do.